# Group input to same row in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using Jquery mobile and would like to group two input buttons (plus/minus) and one input text to the same row using `data-type="horizontal"`.

Fiddle will show how it looks today: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hhken790/4/

I would like to get something similar to:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="notext">Minus</a>
<a href="index.html" data-role="button">Value here</a>
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">Plus</a>
</div>
```

But with the input button support and the value added to input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this effect with the content grid which is provided within jQuery mobile.

```
<div class="QtyWrapper ui-grid-b">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="qtyminus" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">
    <input type="text" name="myInputs[qty][]" value="0" class="qty" class="ui-block-b" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-c">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="qtyplus" class="ui-block-c" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hhken790/5/)

- [jQuery Mobile Content Grids](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0.1/docs/content/content-grids.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this. One easy way is to use a table with fixed width TDs for the buttons:

```
<table class="QtyWrapper">
    <tr>
        <td class="plusminusbtn"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="notext" class="qtyminus">Minus</a></td>
        <td><input class="qty" type="text" value=""    /></td>
        <td class="plusminusbtn"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext"  class="qtyplus">Plus</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>  

.QtyWrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.plusminusbtn {
    width: 1%;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hhken790/7/)**